# Matrix in MySql when I have 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one problem with making matrix in MySql.
I have data like this:

a | 1 | +

a | 3 | +

a | 4 | -

b | 3 | -

b | 1 | +

b | 4 | +

it is possible to make matrix like this:

_|1 3 4

a|+ + -

b|+ - +

????

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of pivot, but with a nuance, because the missing value needs to be replaced by `-`.  In MySQL you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select col1,
       max(case when col2 = 1 then col3 else '-' end),
       max(case when col2 = 3 then col3 else '-' end),
       max(case when col2 = 4 then col3 else '-' end)
from table t
group by col1;
```

Comment: What if you say `max(case when col2 in (1,3,4) then col3 else '-' end)` instead 3 lines. Curious!!

Comment: @Rahul . . . You need three columns, so one expression will not do.